I have a table which has 3 diff status column like status1,status2 and status 3 and for each status I want a separate row
I have a table which has 3 ref no and 3 diff status column like started,pended and closed  and for each status I want a separate row. Addition to that in output we shall have a sequence no column for each status if statuses are started, pended and closed then sequence no will be 1,2 and 3. Multiple rows will be created for each status.
I was not able to do this solution.



Ref no
status1
status2
status 3




1
started
pended
closed


2
started
pended



3
started
pended
closed



output



refno
status
seq no




1
started
1


1
pended
2


1
closed
3


2
started
1


2
pended
2


3
started
1


3
pended
2


3
closed
3




Please read How To Make A Good Example and improve your question as explained.

Please add sample table data to your question.

UNION ALL comes to mind,

Unpivot using UNPIVOT or a LATERAL join fiddle
